# How to Remove the Black bar from Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am looking at the SurfaceViewOverlay example which comes with android-sdk. I am trying to remove the black bar which comes in the bottom. How can I do this ? The XML layout file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Here is where we put the SurfaceView, in a frame so that we can
         stack other views on top of it. -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView android:id="@+id/glsurfaceview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/hidecontainer"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@drawable/translucent_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button android:id="@+id/hideme1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="@string/hide_me"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/hideme2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:text="@string/hide_me"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

        <Button android:id="@+id/vis"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/visibility_1_vis"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/invis"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/visibility_1_invis"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/gone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/visibility_1_gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[Here is a screenshot](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/yq4wj)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i was thinking about stupid things.

A little hack to visual remove the black bar will be to make the last `Linearlayout` to fill the area and then set the background to white(i think this is what you want):

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#ffffff">
//....
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:alpha="0" is making the buttons invisible and only the black bar is visible.

Comment: @user1191140 that space appears because of the last  `LinearLayout`. I've edited my answer.